# How do I import datasets through looping variable assignments?

Tags: python, pandas

I'm trying to import a few different datasets with pandas and assign each to a different variable. I've done this through the following.

```
for i in range(11):
    alphabet = ['a','b','c','d','e','f','g','h','i','j','k']
    globals()['w{}'.format(i)] = 'Combined_{}160c.dta'.format(alphabet[i])
```

This assigns `w1-w11` to '`Combined{a-k}160c.dta'`. i.e. `w5 = 'Combined_f160c.dta'`

But I'm having trouble importing the datasets. Adding the prefix `pd.read_stata` to the above loop comes up with this error.

```
  Input: globals()['w{}'.format(i)] = pd.read_stata('Combined_{}160c.dta').format(alphabet[i])

   Output: FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'Combined_{}160c.dta'
```

How do I change the loop to make it read the a-k instead of the {}?

Answer (score 0):

It is possible if add `.format` with string:

```
globals()['w{}'.format(i)] = pd.read_stata('Combined_{}160c.dta'.format(alphabet[i]))
```

Better should be create dictionary:

```
d = {}
for i in range(11):
    alphabet = ['a','b','c','d','e','f','g','h','i','j','k']
    d['w{}'.format(i)] = pd.read_stata('Combined_{}160c.dta'.format(alphabet[i]))
```

Comment: Ah i see it was just the open bracket. Thanks so much!